# Xampp MYSQL server is not starting after update

Tags: mysql, xampp

my xampp server was working before windows 10 update, and now after update. mysql server is not starting anymore.
Here are the logs.

```
    InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47152; transaction id 9
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200819 23:06:09
2020-08-19 23:06:09 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: the lasr entry shows that the server has started dorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes finally, i have re installed xampp server and that fixed the problem. thank you all.